# How fill length and feature count in PostGIS table for each polygons

Tags: postgis, query

I'am new to PostGIS/PostgreSql. I have a database which containts two shape-files :

1. polygonal layer towns and
2. linear layer of roads

   To calculate the length and feature count of 'Streets' inside each 'Town' use the following query in pgAdmin:

```sql
     SELECT
         m."townname",
         sum(ST_Length_Spheroid(r.the_geom,'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'))/1000 AS Roads_Km,
         count(*) AS Roads_Count
     FROM
         "Streets" AS r,
         "Towns" AS m
     WHERE 
         ST_Intersects(m.the_geom, r.the_geom)
     GROUP BY
         m."townname"
     ORDER BY
         m."townname";
```

and then I save the results in csv table with the fields 'Town name', 'length', 'count'.

I want to add in the 'Town table' the following columns :   'length', 'count' and 'time updates'.

I need some help to create :

1. A query which calculates 'length', 'count' (of linear geometries inside the Towns layer) and 'record resuls' as an attribute column within the 'Towns' Table
2. A new column called 'time updates' within the 'Towns' table which will hold the running time of the query.

   Thanks!

**Updated 10.12.2012**

I've added the following extra informations to help clarify my problem :

1. Polygonal (town) and linear (street) geometry
2. Attribute table for polygonal geometry
3. Result my query in pgAdmin result window

**Updated 12.12.2012**
This is corrected query:

```sql
UPDATE town t SET 
    length = calc.roadskm, -- column length in towns table
    count = calc.roadscount, -- column count in towns table
    updatetime = calc.time -- column updatetime in towns table
FROM (
    SELECT
        m.townname,
        sum(ST_Length_Spheroid(r.the_geom,'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'))/1000 AS roadskm,
        count(*) AS roadscount,
        now() as time
    FROM
        streets AS r, --linear layer of roads
        town AS m --polygonal layer of towns
        WHERE ST_Intersects(m.the_geom, r.the_geom)
    GROUP BY
        m.townname
        ) calc 
WHERE t.townname = calc.townname;
```

[image]

Comment: If you can, it's better not to use capitalized column names. Then you can write `m.townname` instead of `m."TownName"`. In PgAdmin for example, sometimes the capitalized letters are not shown which can be puzzling.

Comment: With the query that you are using, if a road has part of this length outside the town, all the length of road will be counted. If you need a different thing you should change your query

Comment: @Francisco Puga, Thanks! I know. For my data it is necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be syntax problems , but here is example howto use subquery.

```sql
UPDATE Towns t 
     SET t.length = r.Roads_km
        ,t.count = r.Roads_Count
        ,t.updatetime = r.update_time
FROM (
-- subquery
SELECT
     m."TownName"
     ,sum(ST_Length_Spheroid(r.the_geom,'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'))/1000 AS Roads_Km
, count(*) AS Roads_Count
, now() as update_time
FROM
     "Streets" AS r,
     "Towns" AS m
WHERE ST_DWitIn(m.the_geom, r.the_geom,0,1 /* i assume metric srid */  )
GROUP BY
     m."TownName"
ORDER BY
     m."TownName"
) as r 
WHERE t.TownName = r.TownName
```

:Edited to show howto use subquery in update

Comment: Now I have result (length, feature count inside each polygon) linear layer Steeet in pgAdmin Result window (and I save this result in csv table). I want record length, feature count of linear layer Street inside each polygon Towns in polygon attribute table and add time of run query.

Comment: count(r.the_geom) gives you count from used r.the_geom

Comment: Thanks for now() as update_time function! But I need record result in Towns attribute table. How to do it?

Comment: do you mean UPDATE column in Towns table ? English is not my native language.

Comment: Yes, update records in Length, count, time_update columns of Towns attribute table layer after run query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460102/postgresql-using-a-subquery-to-update-multiple-column-values

... update table   set lenght = l , count = c , ut = now() FROM ...

Comment: Please edit your SQL query in answer according to last comment. I try create query...but unsuccessfully:( Thanks!

Comment: update table towns as t set length = sum(ST_Length_Spheroid(r.the_geom,'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'))/1000 , roads_count = count(*) , update_time = now() FROM Streets s WHERE ST_DWitIn(t.the_geom, r.the_geom,0,1) GROUB by t.Townname 

Probably wont work. I dont have any real data in psotgresql at moment so i cant test it .. Another way to update could be subquery with town join

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256610/updating-table-rows-in-postgres-using-subquery

This one has subquery update example

Comment: Thank you for edited question! I try these query, but don't receive correct result. I added some pictures in question. And in my query I used ST_Intersects function instead ST_DWithIn

Comment: I understood query in your answer (some syntax errors). Thank you! I added in my question corrected query.

Answer (score 4):

If your tables geom is not immersivly complex then I suggest a [view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createview.html) would fit your needs better.

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW myview AS
 SELECT
     m."TownName",
     sum(ST_Length_Spheroid(r.the_geom,'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'))/1000 AS Roads_Km,
     count(*) AS Roads_Count,
     now() as 'Time'  --Note: now() returns the time where the query started, not the time it needed to complete. 
 FROM
     "Streets" AS r,
     "Towns" AS m
 WHERE 
     ST_Intersects(m.the_geom, r.the_geom)
 GROUP BY
     m."TownName"
 ORDER BY
     m."TownName";
```

To get your results :

`SELECT * FROM myview;`

A view is basically a query which is being run every time you call it (think it as a shortcut). So if you add more elements in "Towns" and "Roads" table the view will accordingly be updated.

Comment: Thanks you for answer, but result must save in attribute table of Towns layer.