# Counting Points in Polygon with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point-in-polygon, count

I've got a simple problem: I want to count the number of points within a set of polygons.

I have a SQL already but it only gives back the gid of the polygone that actually contains points.

My tables: a polygon layer with 19.000 rows and a point layer with 450 rows.

The following SQL-query

```sql
SELECT grid.gid, count(*) AS totale
FROM grid, kioskdhd3
WHERE st_contains(grid.geom,kioskdhd3.geom)
GROUP BY grid.gid;
```

returns only some 320 polygons that actually contain points. But I want all polygons returned, even thought the number of points is 0.

Of course it has to do with my WHERE-clause. Where do I have to put in my `st_contains()`?

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42951/how-fill-length-and-feature-count-in-postgis-table-for-each-polygons

Comment: thanks, but they all have a WHERE-clause. I don't know if I need one. How would you re-write it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```sql
SELECT grid.gid, count(kioskdhd3.geom) AS totale 
FROM grid
LEFT JOIN kioskdhd3 ON st_contains(grid.geom,kioskdhd3.geom)
GROUP BY grid.gid;
```

Comment: Hi Nicklas, got this answer from the mailing list, right? Thanks everyone

Comment: No, sorry, Is it similar? Well, an outer joins is no rocket science when dealing with relational databases ;-)

Comment: :-) I had to check the list. Look at the timing. My answer here was before list- answer , but as you said, very similar :-)

Answer (score -1):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270786/optimizing-postgis-indexed-query-notice-gserialized-gist-joinsel-jointype-1-n) left joins are not supported in GiST indices.

May I recommend:

```
SELECT grid.gid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN st_contains(grid.geom,kioskdhd3.geom) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM grid, kioskdhd3 
GROUP BY grid.gid;
```

Comment: The querry does not utilize spatial indexes: http://explain.depesz.com/s/U6Iy. Nicklas answer does : http://explain.depesz.com/s/nhH