# Postgis identify points on the polygon border

Tags: postgis, polygon

I have points geom in `gid,pt_geom` and polygon geom in `gid,pl_geom`. Some of the points are inside polygon and some are outside polygon, others are on the polygon boundary.

[image]

Is there any way to identify those points on the polygon by using PostGIS functions (`e.g. ST_contains() or ST_Distance()`)?

Maybe `Select points.gid from points inner join polygon on st_contains(polygon.the_geom,points.the_geom)`.

Comment: So you only want the ones touching the border?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use st_touches but it gives me false when i applied it on the points touching the polygon border.

Comment: Some of my points are not on the vertex of the polygon so the ST_Touches() is not working for those points.

Comment: ST_Touches also returns true if points are on the boundaryand not just on a vertex. This is proved by: "SELECT ST_Touches('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'::geometry, 'POINT(0 0.5)'::geometry);". If ST_Touches returns false above, the points are very close to but not exactly on the boundary. If you manually digitized the example, points are infinitely small and boundaries infinitely narrow, so the likelihood of actually getting a point on the boundary is very low. If you believe the points really are directly on the boundary, your negative result could possibly be due to a rounding error.

Comment: For any really-world example using fractions a point intersects line test- which is really what you are doing- is likely to fail due to use of floating point math.  Convert the polygon boundary to a LINESTRING and use STDistance against that with a suitable buffer (a few centimeters converted to whatever units should do it).

Answer (score 10):

```
Select points.gid 
from points inner join polygon 
on st_dwithin(st_exteriorring(polygon.the_geom),points.the_geom,0.001)
```

Comment: combines well with http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54661/count-points-in-polygon-with-postgis