# Get list of equidistant points on polygon border PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I would like to get points from polygon border using PostGIS.

I've tried using `ST_DumpPoints()` function, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_points_from_polygon(polygon geometry)
RETURNS SETOF geometry AS
$$
DECLARE
    point geometry;
BEGIN
    FOR point IN 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            points.geom 
        FROM (
               SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(polygon)).* 
             ) AS points LOOP
        RETURN NEXT point;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

But it gets sometimes huge list of points (~100-500) and that is not what I need.
I need to get N equidistant points on the border, like on the screenshot attached.
Then, when I have these points I will analyze viewshed polygons from point as observer

I've found, how to [identify is the point on the polygon border](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75910/postgis-identify-points-on-the-polygon-border)
But have no idea , how to create first them and get as a list of points geometry.

What would be your suggestion to do this?

[image]

Comment: try to use: ST_ExteriorRing() and generate_series() and ST_LineInterpolatePoint()...

Comment: Cyril, thank you for the response!
If you have some sample code it would be great, since I'am not close familiar with postgis...

Comment: Great answer, @CyrilMikhalchenko. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script solves your problem:

```
WITH tbla AS (SELECT (ST_ExteriorRing(((ST_Dump(geom)).geom))) geom FROM <table_name>), intervals AS (SELECT generate_series (0, 99) as steps) SELECT steps AS stp, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM intervals)) geom FROM tbla, intervals GROUP BY intervals.steps, geom;
```

Set the required number of points on the line, in my example it is 100...

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly different formulation using `ST_LineInterpolatePoint`.  Note that the number of intervals needs to be substituted in two places.

```
WITH shell AS (
  SELECT ST_ExteriorRing('POLYGON ((5 5, 10 15, 17 10, 5 5))') geom
)
SELECT i, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, (i-1.0)/40) pt
    FROM shell
    JOIN generate_series (1, 40) AS step(i) ON true;
```