# In mapserver, how would I style polygons differently based on a separated points layer?

Tags: postgis, mapserver, mapfile

I have 2 tables in postgis - one of type polygons and one of type points.

I want the color of the polygons to be related to the number of points within each polygon, say white when no points are inside a polygon, pink when 'some' points are inside and red when 'a lot' of points are inside (a full range of colors based on percentage of points/polygon is what I'm really after).

I am using mapserver, and in the [expression section of CLASS](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/class.html) it doesn't mention any way of taking information from another table. Only attributes from within the same table used for the DATA tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do a spatial join in the DATA statemet

```
DATA "geom from (SELECT poly.gid, poly.geom, Count(gid) AS ptcount 
                 FROM poly JOIN pts ON ST_Intersects(poly.geom, pts.com)
                 GROUP BY poly.gid, poly.geom) using unique gid"
```

If your data aren't changing very often, doing this for every map draw is probably not a good performance idea, and you might be better served by creating a [materialized view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) of the result, mapping from that, and updating the view regularly.

Comment: hi! thanks allot! i just found the same thing after struggling with it :) ill delete my answer as yours is more elaborated. again - thanks!

Comment: well there is a tiny difference: you wrote st_intersects and in the post i attached he used st_contains. is there a difference?

Comment: btw, your lectures rock :-)

Comment: For point-in-polygon intersects and contains return identical results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok i have a solution, but if someone has a better one i'd like to hear!

i need to add the count information at the data stage via JOIN as said in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54661/count-points-in-polygon-with-postgis)

then i can use regular classes and styles based on that attribute